# Using Java ProcessBuilder to Execute a Piped Command

Tags: java, command-line

I'm trying to use Java's `ProcessBuilder` class to execute a command that has a pipe in it.  For example:

```
ls -l | grep foo
```

However, I get an error:

```
ls: |: no such file or directory
```

Followed by:

```
ls: grep: no such file or directory
```

Even though that command works perfectly from the command line, I can not get `ProcessBuilder` to execute a command that redirects its output to another.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Note since Java 9 there's [Pipeline#startPipeline(List)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#startPipeline(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 73):

This should work:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l| grep foo");
```

To execute a pipeline, you have to invoke a shell, and then run your commands inside that shell.

Comment: For some reason I also needed to do this for `ls /dev/sd*`  IOW, `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /dev/sd*");` works great, whereas `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "/dev/sd*");` did *not* work.  Guessing it has something to do with vararg interpretation of the `*` in the string...  Seems like a bug to me.  Could also be because of the "special" `/dev` device, not sure.

Comment: It's the shell that expands the wildcard, not ls. If you typed `ls '/dev/sd*'` then that wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 9, there’s [genuine support for piplines in `ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#startPipeline(java.util.List)).

So you can use

```java
List<String> result;
List<Process> processes = ProcessBuilder.startPipeline(List.of(
        new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-l")
            .inheritIO().redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE),
        new ProcessBuilder("grep", "foo")
            .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
    ));
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(processes.get(processes.size() - 1).getInputStream())) {
    result = s.useDelimiter("\\R").tokens().toList();
}
```

to get the matching lines in a list.

Or, for Windows

```java
List<String> result;
List<Process> processes = ProcessBuilder.startPipeline(List.of(
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "dir")
            .inheritIO().redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE),
        new ProcessBuilder("find", "\"foo\"")
            .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
    ));
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(processes.get(processes.size() - 1).getInputStream())) {
    result = s.useDelimiter("\\R").tokens().toList();
}
```

These examples redirect *stdin* of the first process and all error streams to *inherit*, to use the same as the Java process.

You can also call `.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` on the `ProcessBuilder` of the last process, to print the results directly to the console (or wherever *stdout* has been redirected to).

Comment: Great answer. However, I don't think you need to call redirectOutput(PIPE) as that is the default. Similarly, inheritIO() is also not necessary.

Comment: The purpose of `inheritIO()` at the first command, is to set stdin and stderr to `INHERIT`. Since it has the side effect of also setting stdout to `INHERIT`, the subsequent `redirectOutput` is used to set it back to `PIPE`. This is still simpler than `.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT) .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to invoke the shell with the command line as the parameter. After all, it's the shell which is interpreting "|" to mean "pipe the data between two processes".

Alternatively, you could launch each process separately, and read from the standard output of "ls -l", writing the data to the standard input of "grep" in your example.

Comment: Seems to be a good option, better than running several shells to get the proper output. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Skeet could you give an example for your suggestion [read from the standard output of "ls -l", writing the data to the standard input of "grep"] ?

Comment: @DaveTheDane: No, I'm afraid I don't have time to write a full example for an answer that's over 13 years old. I suggest you try doing it yourself and ask a new question with how far you've got and where you've run into problems.

Comment: @Jon Skeet ok, I thought it would be a one-liner. Thanks anyway.