# Java processbuilder - how to execute xargs command

Tags: java, linux, shell, command-line, execute

I'm trying to execute the following command using java processbuilder

`ls | xargs cat > pathtonewFile`

Currently my code is

```
 String command="ls | xargs cat >t"

 ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
 probuilder.start()
```

Currently this executes without an error but a new file is not created.

I've tried below based on another post here: [Problem Using Java ProcessBuilder to Execute a Piped Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776195/problem-using-java-processbuilder-to-execute-a-piped-command)

```
   ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "ls  | xargs cat >        pathtonewfile");
```

The command executes but creates a 0 byte file.

Comment: It strikes me that this problem is most likely to be in the command that you are executing.  Try running the same command from a shell prompt.  One possibility is that the command is being run with the wrong current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the file extension to the path, or adding the file extension to the name of the file.

Comment: Stephen C - if I execute from the command line it works as expected

Comment: I figured out the problem the command                               ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "ls  | xargs cat >        pathtonewfile"); works the problem was the folder where ls was executed contained a folder which was causing an error. The fix was to add a filter to ls (ls *.txt")