# Running multiple unix command using Java ProcessBuildr

Tags: java, unix, process

I am running following unix command using ProcessBuilder and it is working fine.

`String[] commands = {"egrep","search string","fileName"}
ProcessBuilder pb =...`

Now I have an additional requirement to filter the output.

`String [] commands = {"egrep","search string","fileName","|","awk\'$0 >\"time\" && $2==\"INFO\"\'"}`

I am getting error "IO Exception: No such file error". It seems it is considering pipe(|) and other awk command as file.

I also tried adding prefix "bash -c" or "/bin/sh -c" like

```
String [] commands = {"bash","-c","egrep","search string","fileName","|","awk\'$0 >\"time\" && $2==\"INFO\"\'"}
```

Now I am getting error 
"bash -c line0: syntax error near unexpected token 'is'bash:-c line0:"

I also tried giving entire egrep command in single string but it also didn't work.

Please advice what am I missing error to use pipe for filtering the output.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering whether your proposed egrep/awk command line will work - I'm unsure it's what you intend - consider making the full command line a single argument to the -c option of `bash`, so you'll have only three strings involved in the construction of the ProcessBuilder. See [SO question 3776195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776195/using-java-processbuilder-to-execute-a-piped-command) for some more info.