# java command execution escapes '|'

Tags: java, command-line

I have a function to execute a system command:

```
public String cmd(String s) {
    String out = "";
    try {
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = run.exec(s.split(" "));
        pr.waitFor();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
            out+=line+"\n";
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out;
}
```

The command passes through:

```sh
cmd("nmap -sL -n 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}'");
```

Expected Output:

```
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
 ...
```

Actual Output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-12 20:27 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.0 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions answers this well:

- [Using Java ProcessBuilder to Execute a Piped Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776195/using-java-processbuilder-to-execute-a-piped-command#3776277)
- [Java program not getting output from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156422/java-program-not-getting-output-from-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> To execute a pipeline, you have to invoke a shell, and then run your commands inside that shell.

```java
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("bash", "-c", command).start();
```

> `bash` invokes a shell to execute your command and `-c` means commands are read from string. So, you don't have to send the command as an array in `ProcessBuilder`.

#### Adapted to you case

```java
String cmd(String command) {
  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
  builder.redirectErrorStream(true); // add stdErr to output

  Process process = builder.command("bash", "-c", command).start();
    
  StringBuilder processOutput = new StringBuilder(); // add lines easier
  // try-with to auto-close resources
  try (BufferedReader processOutputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));) {
    String readLine;
    while ((readLine = processOutputReader.readLine()) != null) {
      processOutput.append(readLine + System.lineSeparator()); // use system's line-break
    }

    process.waitFor();
  }

  return processOutput.toString().trim();
}
```

Then call as expected:

```java
cmd("nmap -sL -n 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}'");
```

Note: I enhanced it a bit to

- use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to deal cleanly with resources
- add output from [StdErr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))
- use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate output lines
- use [`System.lineSeparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) for platform-independency (Win/Mac/Linux/Unix)

Inspired by:
[read the output from java exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149828/read-the-output-from-java-exec#8150065)

Answer (score 1):

The pipe is interpreted by the shell. It executes one command then passes the output of one command into the next one. You could emulate this in Java starting both commands and then pumping the `OutputStream` of the first program to the `InputStream` of the second.

Alternatively if you don't want to do this you can still call something like "sh -c 'command1 | command2"

Comment: Could you please show an example of emulating the passing of the output of cmd1 to cmd2 ? Thanks.