# How can I push my .sql file (which contains db dump ) to another db on server using Java Code?

Tags: java, process, dump

```
public class DumpFileClass{   

  public static boolean importDump(String host, String username, String password, String database, String dumpFilePath) {
           
            
            String mysqlCommand = "mysql -h " + host + " -u " + username + " -p" + password +" " + database + " < " + dumpFilePath;
            System.out.println(mysqlCommand);
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mysqlCommand);
                logger.trace(process);
                int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                logger.trace(exitCode);
                System.out.println(exitCode);

                return exitCode == 0;
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: I have specified all the correct credentials in the code but it is not pushing the data into the new db even though not throwing any exceptions (program also not terminating). I can do the same process by using cmd prompt but getting trouble with java code

Comment: Java doesn't do redirection like the shell. And don't use Runtime exec(). Use ProcessBuilder instead. Does this answer your question? [Using Java ProcessBuilder to Execute a Piped Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776195/using-java-processbuilder-to-execute-a-piped-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid your dependence on the shell by writing to the process input stream. Also avoid dependence on passing a parameter of the database name to `mysql`, as that's not relevant usually when restoring a dump:

```
    public static boolean importDump(String host, String username, String password, 
            String dumpFilePath) {
        boolean result = false;
        String[] mysqlCommand = { "mysql",  "-h", host, "-u", username, "-p" + password };
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(mysqlCommand).redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT).redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
            Process process = pb.start();
            try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(dumpFilePath));
                OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream()) {
                in.transferTo(out);
            }
            logger.trace(process);
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            logger.trace(exitCode);
            result = (exitCode == 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```